# How can I save line breaks when inserting a node?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, nodes

It seems that the node converts any `< br>` to \n when its being inserted, and my iframe doesnt recognize \n as a new line. Is there any way to save new lines the same as you save spaces? Since `& nbsp;` seems to work great.

```
var el = iframe.contentDocument.createElement("textarea");
html = html.replace(/ /g, '&nbsp;');
html = html.replace(/\t/g, '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;');
el.innerHTML = html;
 var frag = iframe.contentDocument.createDocumentFragment(), node, lastNode;
        while (node = el.firstChild) {
            lastNode = frag.appendChild(node);
        }
        range.insertNode(frag);
```

Comment: please put your code  .

Comment: Don’t use `.innerHTML` to set the value of a `textarea` with JavaScript, use `.value` (and keep line breaks as \n, any HTML tags aren’t allowed inside a textarea).

Comment: Pretty sure you need to remove the `&nbsp;`s from inside the text area as well.

Comment: The text-area is just to clean off any html tags that may be in the content (Its coming from outside-sites). It's then being injected into an iFrame. Which is why I'm looking for a solution simular to the &nbsp, because even though its not an html tag it still registers as a space in the iFrame.

Comment: Keep seeing you struggle at this thing...why reinvent the wheel when there are already so many editors out there that have been used for years and cross browser tested

Comment: It's a personal project, I've already put in about 50 hours and I've gotten it compatible with every major browser and the only bug remaining is this new line stuff and a slight problem with IE and selections. I would feel terrible just giving up now :p